# relative path to material file

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,
I am trying to add some custom materials. To do this I used the  tag in the following way

```
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file:///home/mago/Development/hydro/src/ugv_description/Media/materials.material</uri>
        <name>materials/Black</name>
      </script>
    </material>
```

However, the project is shared via some repositories and I want the other users to run the simulations without having to change the path to the script.
The materials are defined in a ROS package that is shared as well, and I would like to reference it in the SDF file.
Is there any way of doing this?
Thank you,
Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5370/relative-path-to-material-file/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yo could use a relative path and the GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environment variable. For example, in your case:

```
<material>
  <script>
    <uri>file://Media/materials.material</uri>
    <name>materials/Black</name>
  </script>
</material>

export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH:/home/mago/Development/hydro/src/ugv_description/
```

It's very common to use a bash script that sets GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH according to the directory where your resource files are located. Using this method you just need to remember source this script.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2014-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2014-02-05**:
Thank you very much! I will write the script!